# Connectedness $A= \left\{ (x,mx) \mid m \in \mathbb{N}, x \in [ 0 , 1 ] \right\} \cup \left\{ (x,-mx) \mid m \in \mathbb{N}, x \in (0 , 1) \right\}$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Is set $$ A = \left\{ (x,mx) \mid m \in \mathbb{N}, x \in [ 0 , 1 ] \right\} \cup  \left\{ (x,-mx) \mid m \in \mathbb{N}, x \in (0 , 1) \right\} $$ connected?

I tried by dividing the set into two open sets whose union is the whole set and are disjunct and nonempty, but I can't. The problem is the zero.

Comment: A short proof is to note that A is (obviously) path-connected and that path-connectedness implies connectedness.

Comment: Draw the  graph    and put $m=1 , $

Comment: @jasmine "and put =1" ?? And then what?

Comment: @Did it becomes  $y= x$ and $y= -x   $  which is clearly connected  by graph

Comment: @jasmine True, and completely offtopic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** for each $m$ you have a graph of a continuous function from a connected domain. So the set $A$ is a union of a lot of graphs of continuous functions. More than that, note that for each graph of the type $\{(x,-mx):x\in (0,1)\}$ you can add the point $(0,0)$ to the graph because this point is anyway a point in $A$. So that way you get that the intersection of all the graphs in the union is not empty.